# JS - показывать div в зависимости от содержания другого div

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью `js` сделать чтобы блок с классом `item` отображался только если в блоке с классом `title` было слово "Слово"?
(по умолчанию стоит `dispay:none`, нужно чтобы менялось на `display:block`)

```css
.item{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="title">Слово</div>

<div class="item">Нужный блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let title = document.querySelector('.title');

if (title.textContent.includes('Слово')) {
  document.querySelector('.item').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.item{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="title">Слово-пам-пам</div>

<div class="item">Нужный блок</div>
```

Comment: В принципе работает, но есть одно но, если в блоке с классом title будет еще что то кроме слова "Слово", тогда не работает

Comment: @Vitaliy Antal, изменил

Comment: includes не работает в ie, лучше использовать indexOf

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!